# Check if all values of an array are different from '0'

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey I'm trying to run a function that checks every 500ms if ALL the values of an array are different from '0'.

Currently i'm able to check if any are different from '0' but that's not exactly what I want.

The array is of the shape [ decor[i][j], decor[i][j], etc etc] So the part to go through all the array is right.

```
function partiewin()
// On verifie si il y a encore des cases avec pour valeur '0' et si non, on fini la partie
{
    var flag= false
    for (var i=1; i <= hauteur; i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j <= largeur; j++)
        { 
            if( decor[  i ][  j ]!=="0") {
                window.alert("You win");
            }   
        }
    }

}
setInterval(partiewin, 500);
```

Comment: Set a flag `var flag = true` befor you loop. Check to see if the value is zero, if so, that set a flag to false and exit the loop. After the loop check the flag and see if it is false or true. If true, you have what you are looking for.

Comment: Why does `i` and `j` start at one? I'd imagine the loop would go to `0..n-1` and not `1..n` like it seems it is. It seems like it should be: `for (var i=0; i < hauteur; i++)`. But I don't know what "hauteur" means.

Comment: hauteur is height in french and largeur is width, but maybe the first row and column of his game are not part of the game, hence why he doesn't check them. We would need to see the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the flag variable to check if a 0 is there. If it is, the alert won't show up

```
 function partiewin()
    {
        var flag= false
        for (var i=1; i <= hauteur; i++)
        {
            for (j=1;j <= largeur; j++)
            { 
                if( decor[  i ][  j ]=="0") {
                    flag=true;
                }   
            }
        }
    if(!flag) window.alert("You win");
    }
    setInterval(partiewin, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function partiewin()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= hauter; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= largeur; j++)
        {
            if (decor[i][j] === "0")
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    window.alert("You win!");
}
setInterval(partiewin, 500);
```

The function will return without displaying the "You Win!" message if any of the values are 0, but if they are all different, it will proceed to the end and display the "You Win!" message.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

 Could this help? Your version of the code doesnt do anything :/

Comment: Your solution makes no sense.

Comment: He's trying to check that all the values in the matrix are something other than 0, so if any of them are 0 the condition won't be satisfied. In my solution you iterate through the matrix until you find a value which is 0. At that point you set the interval and return, so the code outside the loop bodies is never reached. If all the values in the matrix are different from 0, it will escape the loop bodies and display the "You Win" message. Also, the flagging approach used by loli is less efficient because it will continue checking the rest of the matrix for 0s even after it's already found one.

Comment: Sorry. Just realized the setInterval() needs to be outside the function body. I'm updating the answer to reflect that. After that change it does work. Sorry again.